# How do I pass a user's first name and last name from a user profile page to the title in _layout?

Tags: templating, users

I am trying to pass a member's `firstName` and `lastName` to the title on a member profile page. I am using segment 2 to capture the username. This works well in the `for` loop in the `block`:

```
{% set thePartner = craft.users.username( craft.request.getSegment(2) ) %}
{% for partner in thePartner %}
First Name and Last Name: {{ partner.firstName}} {{ partner.lastName }}
{% endfor %)
```

Outside the `block`, where I set the `<title>`, it doesn't work. Essentially, I would like to set the full name and use it in the title, like:

```
{% set fullname = partner.firstName ~ ' ' ~ partner.lastName %}
```

with something like the following in _layout:

```
<title>{{ fullname }} | {{ siteUrl }} </title>
```

How can I pass the full name through?

Comment: As you probably don't have only profile pages on your site, remember to only render `fullname` into the `<title>` of your `_layout` template if the var is actually set: `{{ fullname ? fullname ~ '|' }}`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're just expecting one, you should only look for one. Then you don't have to use a for loop. Plus, fullName is already an attribute of user models. So you can do this for the title:

```
{% set thePartner = craft.users.username( craft.request.getSegment(2) ).first() %}
<title>{{ thePartner.fullName }} | {{ siteUrl }} </title>
```

If you're still having trouble, it may be with what segments you are pulling from the URL.